# how not to call a function when app opens but call its when coming back from other screen or side navbar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello i have implemented google ads in my app, now i want that when app opens it shouldn't call interstitial ads, but when user come back to first screen from other screen or side nav bar it should call ads. I tried calling function from onresume and removed it from oncreate, still its calling ads when app opens. So please tell me how to solve this issue ?

Comment: You could add it  `onBackPressed` or manage it trough a live data boolean for example.

Comment: on BackPressed its not a good idea

Comment: It can work, it depends in how you are developing everything. You just gave too less information.

Comment: In the future, please don't post pictures of code. That is probably why someone downvoted you. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/506796

Answer (score 1):

First Way -> Show ads in onResume() but load it in onPause() so when you move to another screen, you load it and when you return it it show in onResume() funtion and also if you open it first it not show ads because it not load.

Second Way -> save a count livedata variable in viewmodel and increment it when onResume called, and check if it not equals to 1 (because you not need to show its first time) then show ads.

Comment: when i am performing first way, my app is crashing and second way i don't know how to do it, can u please help?

Comment: what error you get in logcat when app crash?